# Views custom output into specific divs

Tags: views

I am a kind of noobie so excuse me for that.

I am trying to implement [this](http://codecanyon.net/item/multipurpose-bookshelf-slider-jquery-plugin/1985655) into my website.

[image: screenshot]

It is a fancy looking bookshelf gallery. I am using drupal 6.x. I have already set up a view to list out the items I would like to appear in the gallery. In other posts, I saw that if I set up the view output as "fields" I can wrap individual fields into custom divs. That is kind of what I want to achieve. The code I need to alter is the following:

```
<div class="slide_animate">
<div class="products_box" id="products_box_1">
<a href="#" class="product" data-type="book" data-popup="true" data-url="images/01_large.jpg" title="The Title is Optional 1">
<img src="images/01.jpg" alt="" width="81" height="107" /></a>
<a href="#" class="product" data-type="book" data-popup="true" data-url="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C05pGnZQQtE" title="Youtube Video">
<img src="images/02.jpg" alt="" width="71" height="107" /></a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="slide_animate">
<div class="products_box" id="products_box_2">
<a href="#" class="product" data-type="magazine" data-popup="true" data-url="images/magazine_large.jpg" title="info"><img src="images/magazine_health.png" alt="" width="76" height="108" /></a>
<a href="#" class="product" data-type="magazine" data-popup="true" data-url="images/magazine_large.jpg" title="info"><img src="images/magazine_gourmet.png" alt="" width="71" height="100" /></a>
</div>
</div>
```

What I need to know is how to make the view output my field data (node url, img, nodetitle) in specific parts of the HTML (data-url ,img ,title); plus, based on taxonomy terms, form different categories. So my books will be under books, and my DVDs will be under dvd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could alter the output in a template. Go to 'Advanced' and look at 'Theme Information'.

Comment: under views menu, or where advanced?

Comment: Go into your view and on the right-hand side is an 'advanced' link/tab, its in there.

Comment: I swear to everything that is living that there is no advanced link tab in my view. I have 7 boxes: View settings, basic settings, Relationships, Arguments, Fields, Sort Criteria, Filters....

Comment: There are three columns in a view. In column 1 theres title, format, fields, filter criteria, sort by. In column 2 theres page settings, header, footer, pager. In column 3 theres Advanced. If you click the link you get a dropdown with things like contextual filters, no results behaviour and theme information.

Answer (score 0):

When editing the view, under Basic Settings -> Style -> Settings (the "gear" icon) you can choose to group the results by a certain field. Hope this helps.

Comment: So then I can edit the output to group based by certain taxonomy?